# PHPUnit: Get name of test class and method from setUp()?

Tags: php, phpunit

PHPUnit runs the `setUp()` method of a test class prior to running a specific test.

I load up test-specific fixtures for every test in a test class and would prefer not to have to explicitly do so. I would ideally like to handle this automagically in the `setUp()` method.

If the `setUp()` method makes available the test class name and test method name this can be done.

Is the name of the test class and method that is about to be run available to me in the `setUp()` method?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this should be calling `$this->getName()` in `setUp()`.

```
<?php

class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function setUp() {
        var_dump($this->getName());
    }


    public function testMethod()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(4,2+2,'OK1');
    }
}
```

And running:

```
phpunit MyTest.php
```

produces:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.1 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.string(10) "testMethod"


Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 5.00Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

---

In general I'd advise against doing this but there sure are cases where it can be a nice way to do things.

Other options would be to have more than one test class and having all the tests that use the same fixtures together in one class.

Another would be to have private setUp helpers and calling the appropriate one from the test case.

Comment: @jon-cram in order to get name of the current test class, `PHPUnit` itself uses [get_class($this)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) to get the class name including the namespace part

Comment: Notably `getName()` is currently marked as `@internal` to PHPUnit and has a note of being excluded from backwards compatibility. Related `toString()` is also part of `@internal` interface. Seems it's not keen on providing public access to this, even though technically it's there and `public`.

Comment: A small update, in newer versions of phpunit, we have `$this->name()`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you don't want to show the `string(10)` part like in the answer of edorian you can do it like this:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    echo $this->getName() . "\n";
}
```